# Cannot link class with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using 5.2.3 of MVC (with VS 2015). I have created a few classes for use with the Entity Framework. They are in a Model folder. Older class files appear in the Server explorer but these do not. In one class I have the code:

```
public class BookReviews: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

and the Book class for example is quite simple:

```
public class Book
{ 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Author{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookReviews> Reviews { get; set; }

}
```

BUT no matter what I do, clean, rebuild, leave VS and go back in, I can get to a DB explorer view which has older and now unused tables (class file) but not these. Is there a way to force them into the Entity Framework?

[image: Incorrect EF Tables]
Artists and Genres are gone. BUT the book classes...they do not appear. WHY?

Comment: but where is key in the book class  [Key], I am not sure though

Comment: Could you show the screenshot?

Comment: It looks like you just haven't re-deployed the code changes to the database- have you tried @can's suggestion?

Comment: @Ron Please update the question with the solutions you have already acquired, may help to find a solution, I case you haven't found it yet

Comment: I have not found a solution. 1) I am not sure why some classes appeared in the localdb in VS. I didn't put them there. I am not sure why the classes that I want in the DB are not there. They have keys [Key] attribute; the code runs without error. This is a prelim. version using classes for the E.F. instead of DB tables and I thought it was nothing until this stuff started. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `update-database` from the package manager console?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Book
{ 
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Author{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookReviews> Reviews { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: i haven't used the ICollection, so I cant say much

Comment: Yes, I added the Key. Doesn't make a difference. I refresh, rebuild, it just remains the same.

Comment: How does the EF information get to the DB explorer so I can add data to a table as a localdb server.

Comment: Would be beneficial to provide some additional commentary on what you are doing in the code (i.e. adding a `[Key]` attribute to the property that maps to the primary key in the database)

Comment: I ran enable-migrations in the Package Console. It was successful. I ran update-database in the p.c. and it was also successful. YET, those two deleted tables still exist in the E.F. db and the new ones do not.

Comment: @Ron Take a backup of everything, delete the unnecessary classes or objects and update database, may solve it, I don't have much experience with migrations

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your Reviews collection as virtual.

for example:

```
public virtual ICollection<BookReviews> Reviews {get; set;} = new HashSet<BookReviews>();
```

Comment: Add it. Deleted the unused class files. Nothing has changed.

Comment: And the most annoying thing is, in my Default Connection, after I deleted the unused classes, and after I deleted the tables which refer to these classes (and I'm not sure how they got there), and after I ran refresh-database, those deleted classes reappeared and the new ones are nowhere to be found.